# Best way to test Android layout before submitting to market

Tags: android, layout

reading about all these different resolutions and hardwares for Android I am a little unsure if the layout I created for an Samsung Galaxy will actually work the same way on all (most) Android devices.

I did not use anything fancy or complicated. However I had to use fixed width in several places to align text and buttons nicely. ALso there is some text with linebreaks that could look differntly if on narrower screens

How can I be sure that my layout will work on other devices? Or is this actually a no issue? Testing in the debugger is sooooo slow, that I actually never got it to work properly.

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set up multiple emulators with different screen sizes, that simulate the possible targets.

In the emulator Ctrl-F11/12 (thanks @ccheneson) allows you to change the orientation, so that you can test that as well.

The emulator may be slow, but to see how the layouts look like it should be fast enough - you may still test the logic on a real device.
Also emulator speed seems to be highly dependent on the screen size.

Comment: For changing orientation it is F11/F12 - I dont have a F13 on my keyboard :) http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/emulator.html

Comment: Thanks - I learned a lot by checking this - what to do in layouts and what to avoid.... Only one advice, never use absolute sizes for width and height...